# How to call values in nested dictionary-Python/Openerp

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, openerp-7

I am trying to access to a value which is in nested dictionary and getting end up with ;

```
raise ValueError("Invalid field %r in leaf %r" % (left, str(leaf)))
ValueError: Invalid field 'att_date_date' in leaf "<osv.ExtendedLeaf: ('att_date_date', '<=', '2017-08-01') on on_call_days (ctx: )>"
```

Please help me to fix this. My classes and other necessary expressions are like bellow;

class **on_call_days** fields;

```
'employee_id': fields.many2one('hr.employee', "Employee"),
'catagory_id':fields.related('employee_id', 'category', string='Emp Category', relation='hr.employee',store=True),
'oc_date':fields.date('From Date'),
'oc_amount':fields.float('Amount for the period'),
'processed_flag':fields.boolean("Entered flag"),
```

class **allowance_attendances** fields;

```
'employee_id': fields.many2one('hr.employee', "Employee"),
'catagory_id':fields.related('employee_id', 'category', string='Emp Category', relation='hr.employee',store=True),        
'attendance_id':fields.integer("Attendance ID"),
'att_date':fields.char("Date"),
'att_date_date':fields.date("Date Date"),
```

class **allowance_request** fields and this is the class which I  tried to use those expressions.

```
    'allowance_attendances_id':fields.one2many('allowance.attendances','allowance_request_id','Allowance Attendance'),
    'oc_days_id':fields.one2many('on.call.days','allowance_request_id','On Call Days'),
```

What I tried to do is

```
   def onchange_employee(self, cr, uid, ids, employee_id,start_date,end_date,context=None):

        DATETIME_FORMAT2 = "%y/%m/%d"
        allo_att_obj=self.pool.get('allowance.attendances')
        on_call_obj=self.pool.get('on.call.days')
        val = {'value': {'allowance_attendances_id': [],'oc_days_id':[]}}
         if end_date:                

                filt +=[('att_date_date','<=', end_date)]            
            if start_date :              

                filt += [('att_date_date','>=', start_date)]
```

There are other stuff going on here for this function and it will **return val** at the end.

The issue is coming from **filt +=[('att_date_date','<=', end_date)]** where I tried to retrieve value from that nested dictionaries. Please help met to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you didn't defined the filt, so probably you get the traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<input>", line x, in <module>
NameError: name 'filt' is not defined
```

so I changed code as:

```
def onchange_employee(self, cr, uid, ids, employee_id,start_date,end_date,context=None):

    DATETIME_FORMAT2 = "%y/%m/%d"
    allo_att_obj=self.pool.get('allowance.attendances')
    on_call_obj=self.pool.get('on.call.days')
    val = {'value': {'allowance_attendances_id': [],'oc_days_id':[]}}
    filt = []
    if end_date:                

            filt +=[('att_date_date','<=', end_date)]            
        if start_date :              

            filt += [('att_date_date','>=', start_date)]
```

If it doesnt helps please get me the log.